# LibreOffice Base Brings in all visible databases as list of tables

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, connectivity

I'm trying to connect to a singer database through LibreOffice Base.  The connection goes fine and successful.  However, when selecting tables, it's showing a list of all the visible Databases in the list.

The list includes mysql, performance_scheme, phpmyadmin, and others which are unrelated to the database in question could be dangerous in the wrong environment.

I have recreated deleted and recreated the database using LibreOffice Base' **Database Wizard** numerous times.  I'm performing these steps to do it again.

---

### Steps for Connecting to the Mysql Database

From **LibreOffice** -> **File** -> **New** -> (Database Wizard) -> (tick) **Connect to an exiting database** -> (select) **MySOL** -> (click) **Next** -> (tick) **Connect directly**

Then I fill out the form with:

**Database Names:** test
**Server:** localhost

Then I click **Next** -> (I enter username and check Password required and click) **Test Connection** -> (The results is successful). -> **OK**

(click) **Next** -> (yes register, open for editing , click) **Finish** (click) **Save**

---

At this point, I'm in configuration with a list of all the visible databases listed as tables with dropdowns.  The tables for each of the databases on the service can be seen by clicking to expand the dropdowns associated with each database.

Can someone tell me how to access a single database, not all of them, whereas the tables will include only the list of tables that are in the specific database?

Is this a bug with the new LibreOffice?

---

**My Operating system and version:**

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
LibreOffiice: Version: 6.0.7.3
MySQL Connector: Built-in - version 1.0.2

Comment: I guess the reason for this is that "databases" in MySQL are in fact [schemas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html) (that is, namespaces for database objects).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll do research to test how to change name spaces and find one that works.